# Migartion of vue2 to vue 3 - how to update the mixins added in vue2 components in vue3 setup api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

We have been lately started migration of our app to vue 3 from vue2 and some components have mixins added and i was wondering how can i add this in vue 3

I tried several solutions on this and couldn't find any special hook as available in vue 2

export default {
name: "Modal",
components: { Loader },
mixins: []
}`how can i add mixins`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 3, you can still use mixins in a similar way to Vue 2 when using the Options API:

```
const mixin = {
  created() { console.log('Mixin'); },
};

export default {
  name: "Modal",
  components: { Loader },
  mixins: [mixin]
};
```

But as for the Composition API, you have to use composable functions instead:

```
// Composable declaration function
import { onMounted } from 'vue';

export function useMixin() {
  onMounted(() => console.log('Mixin'));
  return {};
}

// In your component
import { useMixin } from './mixin';
import Loader from './Loader';

export default {
  name: "Modal",
  components: { Loader },
  setup() {
    useMixin();
    return {};
  },
};
```

Composable functions provide a more explicit and flexible alternative to mixins when using Vue 3's Composition API.